# Insert Pictures in Java

Tags: java, image, background

I want to insert a picture so i can change the background. I've done this with colors like 
" else if (e.getSource() == bla) panel.setBackground(Color.white); " but is there any way to do it with a picture (ex. picture.jpg)?

```
rodbild = new JMenuItem("Röd bild", new ImageIcon("desktop/Rod.jpg"));
```

...

```
else if (e.getSource() == blabild) panel.setBackground(Color.white);
```

that is what i've done so far with just colors.

Answer (score 0):

What I'd suggest here is to insert a PNG image with transparent background on to your panel.

Since the image background is transparent, it will "inherit" the background colour of the panel it's sitting on.

Then when you update the panels background colour (as you're doing already) it should change the background colour surrounding the image just fine.